# Sublime text 2 Zend Framework plugin for completions

Tags: zend-framework, sublimetext2

Does anybody knows good completion plugin for Sublime text 2 for Zend Framework 1.11. I'm trying to switch to it from NetBeans but I'm missing the autocompletion of the classes, methods, etc.

Thanks,
--Yasen

Comment: as if eclipse themes are not good enough for you

Comment: I tried ST2 for a few weeks, then switched back to netbeans - the autocomplete just isn't good enough and the editor lacks certain features. You could however try this; https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel although for me it was kind of useless

Answer (score 0):

Sad. There is no auto-completion function for Sublime text 2 when trying to use Zend classes and methods. Hope that such package would show up sometime